# Bash SCP CRON not working

Tags: bash, shell, cron, scp

I have a file with the following code in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
scp -r -P 2222 -i /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key /opt/storage/test/* root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/opt/storage/test/
```

Now when I put this into the cron tab it runs but there is no error nothing happens. What is the problem?

This is how it it set in the cron tab:

```
*/5 * * * * root /bin/bash /opt/crons/testCopy >> /opt/crons/mylog.log 2>> /opt/crons/err.log
```

Comment: what is root for a command?

Comment: root is the user that is executing the command not sure what you are asking

Comment: what Ronan just answered ;)

Comment: When you say "there is no error nothing happens", you mean you've looked at both the log files and they're empty, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the cron tab executed was perfect the problem in the end was that I was developing on a windows computer and the format of the line endings was incorrect which resulted in the scp not executing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your command as root you should put this line in your root user's crontab, like this:

1. Login as root with `su`
2. Edit your root user's crontab with `crontab -e`
3. Write your cron job in the editor that opens up

Answer (score 0):

The script and cron look good.

Please check that the script

> /opt/crons/testCopy

has permissions 0600, otherwise it will not run. I use 0600, but the only thing needed is that GROUP and OTHERS do not have any access to the file. This is a security measure.

execute this:

```
sudo chmod 0600 path/to/file
```

Comment: "-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  114 Feb  8 21:26 testCopy"
This is from a ls -l

Comment: @Jed 0600 means no read/write/execute for anyone but root user. It should look -rw-------

Comment: Yes but it has more access the 0600 so I dont see why it wouldnt run

Comment: @Jed because it is a security measure. Just do it and test please.